# How to recognize extension method from assembly?

Tags: c#, clr, coreclr

As far as I know, the C# extension method has the attribute of 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'

so i wrote simple test and I check with ilspy and this does not exist there.
I also on creating an object instance and investigating the instance method - I can't recognize if some method is an extension method or not.

I also look on the il viewer but on the viewer i see the 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'

I looking for another way to know if some object/assembly method are extension method from runtime code.

(.net core 6.0)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easily, just check whether a given [`MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=net-6.0) has the [`ExtensionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute?view=net-6.0) applied to it using the [`GetCustomAttributes(Type, bool)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-memberinfo-getcustomattributes(system-type-system-boolean)) method

So:

```cs
public static bool IsExtensionMethod(this MethodInfo method)
{
    // The 'false' is because static classes must derive from 'object'
    // So checking for inherited attributes is unnecessary
    return method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false).Length > 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LNPEnb)

---

FWIW I recommend not looking at IL directly (unless you *really* need to), instead I recommend you use something like [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgDRkgDUAPgAEADAAIBARgB0AJQhgiEBjHTMA3AFgAUMLFTpcbOgC2ESQGECRvOgUIAyrgBu6Big2atAgMxiATLoB2LQBvLRFwv18wiNDNCPiRRygEEXQRAF4RIXcEiPRJAElkACF0WlpcAApxIQBKHIiAX2jwrWaPbXEANj8RAFEADxwWFUwQlrEfCR7gAmIRItLyqpgAC3RkVOxEqCI4CA4tmBECNdxaidjc8IEAnb2IEQA+E7OEBvD2xqA=) to decompile the C# code to actually see what gets compiled, as "code lowering" (sometimes also called desugaring/ stripping syntactic sugar away) is one of the first steps the compiler does

Comment: its good - but its possible to do it without reflection ?

Comment: You're trying to figure out metadata about a method at runtime, so no. Unless you're willing to statically define a list of methods that are extension methods and manually keep that list up to date, but even then you'll somehow need to get a method at runtime which involves some reflection. So, counter question, why not use reflection for what it's intended?

Comment: I trying to study and improve my knowledge and understanding. I trying to know if the ilspy also using reflection or maybe mono.cecil ( that not using reflection )

Comment: but on the mono.cecil that also does not detect extension from what I check on their code